# Getting the picture to the right and the text on the left

Tags: html, css, image, alignment

So shortly explained I've been trying to move the picture to the right and my text to the left of it! I will paste the code here as well as the picture of the website.
Thanks in advance!
**Code**

HTML:

```
<!----- offer -----> 
    <div class="offer">
      <div class="small-container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-2"></div>
            <img src="/bilder/exklusiv.png" alt="" class="offer-img">
          <div class="col-2">
            <p>Exclusively Avalible on Sveriges Vintage</p>
            <h1>Smart Band 4</h1>
            <small>Använd av ingen mindre än Amelia Bodehag (Svensk Influencer)
              Fairfeld Univeristy sweatshirten är ett väldigt sällsynt plagg
              från Champion och finns bara hos oss.
            </small>
            <a href="" class="btn"> Buy Now &#8594;</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
/* Offer */ 
.offer {
  background: radial-gradient(#fff, #ffd6fa);
  margin-top: 80px;
  padding: 30px 0;
}

.offer-img {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  float: left;
}

.col-2 .offer-img {
  padding: 50px;
} 

small {
  color:#555;
}`
```

[image: How it looks]

Comment: Have you tried bootstrap 4? Or CSS Grid? Or the simplest way - using a table? There are so much good tutorials and wikis out there in the network

Comment: FYI: the css rule `.col-2 .offer-img` is not applicable to the markup shown

Comment: @ykostov Thanks for the help, well this is for a school project so we arent allowed to use bootstrap, etc!

Comment: @ykostov using a table for styling purpose is a bad use. You never should do that as tables are for tabular data only (with exeption of e-mail templates). The simplest way would to use float. However the most practicable tool would be Flexbox. Grid is way above what is necessary.

Comment: I would also use flex, it is surprisingly easy to use. You can achieve most of what you want just by giving .row{ display:flex; }

Answer (score 2):

You could get rid of the float and place a `display:flex;` on the ***row*** class (***parent***) element of the two ***col-2*** classes. Place the image tag inside the empty ***col-2*** element and then move it behind the other ***col-2*** element that has the **p**, **h1** and **small** tag. Then you can further embellish flex properties as you like.

```html
<div class="row"><!--/ Add display flex to this elements css /-->  
  <div class="col-2"><!--/ By default this will display in a row /-->
    <p>Exclusively Avalible on Sveriges Vintage</p>
    <h1>Smart Band 4</h1>
    <small>Använd av ingen mindre än Amelia Bodehag (Svensk Influencer)
              Fairfeld Univeristy sweatshirten är ett väldigt sällsynt plagg
              från Champion och finns bara hos oss.
    </small>
    <a href="" class="btn"> Buy Now &#8594;</a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-2"><!--/ By default this will display in a row /-->
    <img src="/bilder/exklusiv.png" alt="" class="offer-img">
  </div>
</div>
```

```css
.offer {
  background: radial-gradient(#fff, #ffd6fa);
  margin-top: 80px;
  padding: 30px 0;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.offer-img {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
}

.col-2:nth-of-type(1){
  /* may want to create a dynamic width that will scale to view port here */
  margin-right: 1rem;
}

small {
  color: #555;
}
```

```html
<div class="offer">
  <div class="small-container">
    <div class="row">      
      <div class="col-2">
        <p>Exclusively Avalible on Sveriges Vintage</p>
        <h1>Smart Band 4</h1>
        <small>Använd av ingen mindre än Amelia Bodehag (Svensk Influencer)
              Fairfeld Univeristy sweatshirten är ett väldigt sällsynt plagg
              från Champion och finns bara hos oss.
            </small>
        <a href="" class="btn"> Buy Now &#8594;</a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-2">
        <img src="/bilder/exklusiv.png" alt="" class="offer-img">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Using Grid: You can set up the ***row*** to be `display: grid`, then move the ***image*** tag inside the empty ***col-2***. Each ***col-2*** though you add a unique selector, then you can use `grid-template-areas` to identify which unique element you wish to be first using grid-area in its CSS.

```css
.row {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr; 1fr;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-areas: "offerText img"
}

.offerText {
  grid-area: offerText;
}

.img {
  grid-area: img;
}
```

Note the `grid-template-columns`, basically you are telling the code that you want each element to be one equal fraction of that parent elements, the grids elements, width. With `grid-template-rows` there is only one row, so we define it as one fraction, so it will take up all of the parent elements height. Then with `grid-template-areas` we very literally tell it which element will be where in the layout by adding its unique selector there. `grid-template-areas: "offerText img"` lastly, each child element will have a grid-area that will list its own element.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.offer {
  background: radial-gradient(#fff, #ffd6fa);
  margin-top: 80px;
}

.row {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  gap: 0px 0px;
  grid-template-areas: "offerText img";
}

.offerText {
  grid-area: offerText;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center
}

.img {
  grid-area: img;
  padding-right: 1rem;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.offer-img {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
}

p,
h1,
small {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 1rem;
}

small {
  color: #555;
}
```

```html
<div class="offer">
  <div class="small-container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-2 img">
        <!-- Move image inside this div -->
        <img src="/bilder/exklusiv.png" alt="" class="offer-img">
      </div>

      <div class="col-2 offerText">
        <p>Exclusively Avalible on Sveriges Vintage</p>
        <h1>Smart Band 4</h1>
        <small>Använd av ingen mindre än Amelia Bodehag (Svensk Influencer)
              Fairfeld Univeristy sweatshirten är ett väldigt sällsynt plagg
              från Champion och finns bara hos oss.
            </small>
        <a href="" class="btn"> Buy Now &#8594;</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```